# Changing the BIRT hyperlink at run time

Tags: birt

Is my expectation valid? If yes, please guide me.

Local machine->local server process-> I generate Birt report-> which contain hyperlinks hard coded for example: http://www.ip_one.com/birtserver/parameters...(this is fine and points to another report and get me the report also when I hit the Url from inside the generated pdf report).

Now, what I need is to change ip_one to suppose ip_two once I hit the hyperlink which is inside the pdf(on the fly)  keeping all the other parts of the url intact.

I am using birt-rcp-report-designer-4_2_2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to dynamically create a hyperlink at report run time.

In the properties editor of the report item that has your link (i.e. label), edit the hyperlink.  In the Hypelink Options (pop-up) to the left of "Location" field is the button ab| select 'JavaScript' Syntax.

You will be able to create the URL using JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry for not being clear in my question. I'm trying to modify the hyperlink not create. Or, you can say both are same. I'm not sure.

Comment: Let me try again. When I generate my final report, I get hard coded hyperlink inside that report. Now, when I click on those links they redirect to the sever machine which is in my LAN. So, anyone inside my LAN can access it. But, I want this embedded report link to be accessible to people outside of my LAN too. So, here I'm trying to have a check/ way in place to modify the IP itself at runtime. Also, I'm aware of javascript option but don't know how to start. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Once the report is written it becomes difficut to change, you will want to identify which link to use so the correct one is there in the begining There are a number of tutorials and examples of modifing hyperlinks at http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/news-events/search/?q=hyperlink   Also for simular issues I have seen it recomended to have two labels with the different items (i.e. links) then use the visibility property of the label to hide the one you don't want at run time.

Comment: @Tirath - "to be accessible to people outside of my LAN" is there some reason to not use the outside the LAN link for everyone?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out and update the same here...yes that is possible but not feasible as its not the report that matters, its the files which my report points to and it comes to around a GB(weekly). Copying a GB & waiting for it on weekly basis(I don't want this). The other reason is firewall. Its like - 1 master, 2 slave. Master can peek into the slaves networks but the same is not an option when it comes to slaves. Their interaction is prohibited by the firewall.